# React Native Video replay from beginning

Tags: ios, video, react-native

I've been using the React Native Video module and its working great, however I need the video on playback end to automatically rewind back to the beginning. The video instance has the option to use:

```
onEnd={this.onEnd}
```

To call a function when video playback finishes, and also seems to have this function:

```
seek(seconds)
```

But I'm not sure how its used exactly. I need to set the video to 0 time index at playback end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to start playback again immediately, you can you use the 'repeat' property. If you really just want to reset it without playing, then you need to use seek(). But as far as I know the video component doesn't expose the seek function of the underlying video player directly, but via it's refs. You can use

```
myVideo.refs.node.seek(0)
```

where *myVideo* is a reference to your video component.

Comment: Ok I have:  var Video = require('react-native-video');  so I used your code in an onEnd function like this: Video.refs.node.seek(0)  but it just returns undefined is not an object. If that's not how I refer to the video component then I'm not sure how.

Comment: You need to use a ref. <Video .... ref='myVideo' /> and then in onEnd this.refs.myVideo.refs.node.seek(0)

Comment: Or you create the component via the API and not via JSX and keep a reference.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean there. I'm new to React Native. What would the actual code be? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Its alright I got it working in the end! Thanks for your help.

Comment: This worked for me > videoRef.current?.seek(0)

Comment: ` playerRef.current.seek(0);`  is works!